# Changing a Parents Key with a subarray value 3 Dimensional Array

Tags: php

So the code below is mainly to generate the same Array I have, This array is generated via some other process that I do not have control over thus direct editing is not possible.

What I need to do is change the key that outputs on the second tier array
Array with the 'uid' on the 3rd array.  Below I have a visual of what it looks like now and what I need it to be.

```
<pre>

(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 155
            [amount] => 45
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 156
            [amount] => 45
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 157
            [amount] => 45
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 158
            [amount] => 45
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 159
            [amount] => 45
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 160
            [amount] => 45
        )

)

Desired Output

Array
(
    [155] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 155
            [amount] => 45
        )

    [156] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 156
            [amount] => 45
        )

    [157] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 157
            [amount] => 45
        )

    [158] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 158
            [amount] => 45
        )

    [159] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 159
            [amount] => 45
        )

    [160] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 160
            [amount] => 45
        )

)
</pre>
```

I have tried some for each loops but they have generated some strange output and I have attempted to pass the value during the 2cnd tier array via array_push but only got errors.

```
$p_array = array(
$alpha = array('uid' => 155,'amount' => 45),
$alpha = array('uid' => 156,'amount' => 45),
$alpha = array('uid' => 157,'amount' => 45),
$alpha = array('uid' => 158,'amount' => 45),
$alpha = array('uid' => 159,'amount' => 45),
$alpha = array('uid' => 160,'amount' => 45)
);
print_r($p_array);
```

Comment: So that code is just to generate the array, $alpha is used as a placeholder. 
The idea is to just make an the array I am working with but the actual code is sensitive info, So the code that generates the array will not be edited I just need to manipulate the $p_array   array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most elegant solution would be to use a reduction:

```
<?php

$p_array = array(
    $alpha = array('uid' => 155,'amount' => 45),
    $alpha = array('uid' => 156,'amount' => 45),
    $alpha = array('uid' => 157,'amount' => 45),
    $alpha = array('uid' => 158,'amount' => 45),
    $alpha = array('uid' => 159,'amount' => 45),
    $alpha = array('uid' => 160,'amount' => 45)
);

$result = array_reduce(
    $p_array,
    function($acc, $cur) {
        $acc[$cur['uid']] = $cur;
        return $acc;
    },
    array()
);

print_r($result);
```

[`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-reduce.php) will start with the initial value (which is an empty array in our case) and then for each element call the callback with two elements: 1st the accumulator and 2nd the current item. The accumulator is initialized with our initial value (empty array) and then passed along with each consecutive call. Hence it is imporant to return the `$acc` after you've done modifying it.

Then to finally do the transformation you where asking for you put the current element into the accumulator with an index using the `uid` key of the current element: `$acc[$cur['uid']] = $cur;`

Comment: Thank you! I will test this to see if this works better! I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

There's a function for that:

```
$result = array_column($array, null, 'uid');
```

If you wanted to loop or if you have an old PHP version:

```
foreach($array as $v) {
    $result[$v['uid']] = $v;
}
```